# Field Options are not visible (MSM)

Tags: custom-fields, multi-site-manager

I use msm for two sites, and my dir structure is as follows:

Home>site1>docroot>themes
Home>site2>docroot>themes
Home>EEcommon>system (EE system folder)

When I try to create a new channel field or edit existing ones on site1, it shows Field Settings, but it doesn't show Field Options.  site2 works properly, no problem at all. I copied themes folder of site2 to site1, but no change, still I cannot see field options on site1. Any idea?
Cheers,
Ahmet